# mySQL many-to-many LEFT JOIN syntax

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 mySQL InnoDB tables:

**Books**
A_ID smallint(5) unsigned auto increment Primary Key
Title varchar(60)

**Authors**
B_ID smallint(5) unsigned auto increment Primary key
Name varchar(30)

**Author_Book** *the many-to-many table*
A_ID smallint(5) unsigned
B_ID smallint(5) unsigned
PRIMARY KEY (A_ID,B_ID)
FOREIGN KEY(A_ID) REFERENCES Authors(A_ID)
FOREIGN KEY(B_ID) REFERENCES Books(B_ID)

I'm not understanding how to use LEFT JOINs with a many-to-many table:  say, to show the authors for each book.  I tried this query which seemed to be logical but no luck:

```
SELECT Books.Title, Authors.Name 
FROM Books LEFT JOIN ON Books.B_ID = Author_Book.B_ID 
LEFT JOIN ON AuthorBook.A_ID = Authors.A_ID;
```

Am I way off base or are there punctuation/syntax errors in my query?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No. See LEFT JOIN syntax.

Comment: [From One-to-Many to Many-to-Many](http://buysql.com/mysql/59-one-to-many.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Books.Title, Authors.Name 
FROM Books LEFT JOIN Author_Book ON Books.B_ID = Author_Book.B_ID 
LEFT JOIN Authors ON AuthorBook.A_ID = Authors.A_ID;
```

Comment: My (rookie) question answered; consider this topic closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try using inner join as the second one, but here the issue is that you missed the tables to join:

`SELECT Books.Title, Authors.Name FROM Books LEFT JOIN Author_Book ON Books.B_ID = Author_Book.B_ID LEFT JOIN Authors ON AuthorBook.A_ID = Authors.A_ID;`

Or, if you don't need authors with no books for example:

`SELECT Books.Title, Authors.Name FROM Books INNER JOIN Author_Book ON Books.B_ID = Author_Book.B_ID INNER JOIN Authors ON AuthorBook.A_ID = Authors.A_ID;`